# C# updating database record

Tags: c#, sql, linq

im having trouble updating a record in a table from my c# code. I have my database mapped to my c# classes and inserting works but updating is giving issues.

```
int id = 1;

DataContext dc = new DataContext(connString);
var tbl = dc.GetTable(Person);
var p = tbl.Where(x => x.id == id).First();
p.name = "abc";
p.location = "xyz";

p.SubmitChanges();
```

This just inserts a new record with the same info as the initial Person but with the changed fields as specified. Could this have anything to do with having the id column in the Person class to be IsDbGenerated?
Also if my person class has relationships with other classes like if location were a Location object could this be causing me issues?

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? Also should `p.SubmitChanges()` be `dc.SubmitChanges()`?

Comment: try `dc.Person.Attach(p,true);  `

Comment: @Laurence sorry yes I typed this up as I don't have my code right now it should say dc.SubmitChanges();

Comment: Are name or location part of the PK?

Comment: @Krumelur no the PK is just an int

Comment: is PK this id field? (just to be sure)

Comment: Make sure your database model and dbml are in sync.